# Google App Script Key Value Pair by Header

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create key value pairs using the header column and although I'm able to get the values my forEach is grouping all values by date or description as opposed to each item in each row show in ideal out put.

There might be a much easier way of doing this than my approach so open to suggestions if there is tried and true approach for app script, which I'm just learning here.

[image]

```
function tableToObject () {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const transactionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Transactions')

const lastRow = transactionSheet.getLastRow()
const lastColumn = transactionSheet.getLastColumn()

const originalData = transactionSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow - 1,lastColumn).getValues()

Logger.log(originalData)

const headers = originalData[0] // Extract headers
Logger.log(headers)

const body = originalData.slice(1)

const keys = {}
let i = 0

headers.forEach(function (c) {
keys[c] = [] 
body.map(r => keys[c].push(r[i]))
i++})
Logger.log(keys)
```

}

Ideal Output

```
[{
  "date": "1/4/2019",
  "category": "Source A",
  "amount": "100",
  "month": "January",
  "year": "2019",
  "group": "COGS",
  "debit/credit": "Credit",
},  {
      "date": "1/4/2019",
      "category": "Source A",
      "amount": "100",
      "month": "January",
      "year": "2019",
      "group": "COGS",
      "debit/credit": "Credit",
    }
]
```

Final Code

```
function tableToObject() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 const transactionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Transactions');
 const lastRow = transactionSheet.getLastRow();
 const lastColumn = transactionSheet.getLastColumn();
 const values = transactionSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow,lastColumn).getValues();
 const [headers, ...originalData] =   values.map(([,b,,d,e,,,,,,,,,,,p,q,r,s]) => [b,d,e,p,q,r,s]);
 const res = originalData.map(r => headers.reduce((o, h, j) => Object.assign(o, { [h]: r[j] }), {}));
 console.log(res)

 const result = [...res.reduce((r, o) => {
 const key = o.Category + '_' + o.Month + '_' + o.Year
 const item = r.get(key) || Object.assign({}, o, {
   Amount: 0,
})

 item.Amount += o.Amount
 item.Key = key
 return r.set(key, item)
}, new Map).values()]
console.log(result)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- About `const originalData = transactionSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow - 1,lastColumn).getValues()`, in this case, the last row is not retrieved.
- In your `forEach`, each column value is put in an array. In this case, from your expected output value, I thought that each column value is required to be the object with the header key and the value.

When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function tableToObject() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const transactionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Transactions');
  const lastRow = transactionSheet.getLastRow();
  const lastColumn = transactionSheet.getLastColumn();
  const [headers, ...originalData] = transactionSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).getValues();
  const res = originalData.map(r => headers.reduce((o, h, j) => Object.assign(o, {[h]: r[j]}), {}));
  console.log(res)
}
```

- If you don't want to retrieve the last row, please modify `lastRow` to `lastRow - 1`.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

### Added:

About your following new question,

> Other than the spacing in the header row it works like a charm. One question, if I only wanted to return column, B, E, P, Q, R and S to avoid changing the header names for the other columns which come back as for example 'Account #': 'xxxx8366',. How might I do that?

> If you look in the screenshot there are column A:T but I really only need A, D, E, P, Q, R and S. I was curious if we can output only that only, see updated output for a sample.

How about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function tableToObject() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const transactionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Transactions');
  const lastRow = transactionSheet.getLastRow();
  const lastColumn = transactionSheet.getLastColumn();
  const values = transactionSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).getValues();
  const [headers, ...originalData] = values.map(([a,,,d,e,,,,,,,,,,,p,q,r,s]) => [a,d,e,p,q,r,s]);
  const res = originalData.map(r => headers.reduce((o, h, j) => Object.assign(o, { [h]: r[j] }), {}));
  console.log(res)
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much, other than the spacing in the header row it works like a charm.  

One question, if I only wanted to return column, B, E, P, Q, R and S to avoid changing the header names for the other columns which come back as for example 'Account #': 'xxxx8366',.  How might I do that?

Comment: @JAK Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question? For example, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question.

Comment: Goodness, no apologizes you've been super helpful.  sorry it wasn't clear.  If you look in the screenshot there are column A:T but I really only need A, D, E, P, Q, R and S.  I was curious if we can output only that only, see updated output for a sample.

Comment: @JAK Thank you for replying. About your new question, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Awesome, working perfectly here is the part of my final solution.